# Bootstrap vertical aligned without breaking the grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment

I been trying all the different options that I found to vertically align a grid. Because of the layout that I have none of them worked.

This is what I have to do: for COL-MD and COL-LG the layout should be:

```
DIV1-IMG     DIV2-TEXT
DIV3-TEXT    DIV4-IMG
```

In this case the DIV-TEXT has to be vertically aligned.

For COL-SM and under, the layout should be:

```
DIV1-IMG
DIV2-TEXT
DIV4-IMG (if it is complicated, we can stick to first show DIV3-TEXT and then DIV-4-IMG)
DIV3-TEXT
```

The problem is that if I set the div to display:table and its variants, the grid breaks and it doesn't resize to col-xs.

Here I set up the example in case you can see what I am trying to accomplish: http://www.bootply.com/nCIExg8DkM

Any ideas on how one can align the text vertically without breaking the grid?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use [media queries](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries) to reduce the coverage area of your style: `@media (min-width: 992px) {}`.
2. Use `.col-md-push-6` and `.col-md-pull-6` modifier classes to [change the order of your columns](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering).
3. Simplify classes:

   - `col-xs-12 col-lg-6 col-md-6` is equal to `col-md-6`.
   - `col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-8 col-md-offset-1 col-md-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10` is equal to `col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-8 col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10`.
4. Use special helpful classes:

   - [The `.img-responsive` class](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images-responsive) scales the image nicely to the parent element.
   - [The `.center-block` class](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-center) aligns the block via margin.

Check the result: http://www.bootply.com/WEf5cQlDog

```css
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .vertical-middle > div {
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-8">
      <div class="row vertical-middle">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <img src="http://www.hercampus.com/sites/default/files/2013/02/27/topic-1350661050.jpg" class="center-block img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
          <h2>Title 1</h2>                          
          <p>Text to be centered</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row vertical-middle top-buffer">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-6">
          <img src="http://www.hercampus.com/sites/default/files/2013/02/27/topic-1350661050.jpg" class="center-block img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-pull-6 text-center">
          <h2>Title 2</h2>
          <p>Text to be centered</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gleb, thank you very much. It works great! Regarding the change of order in the columns I couldn't make it work. When the image is on the right div (only for col-sm), I would like to push it up so the text (which is on the left DIV) comes after the image. Here I left the code but it doesn't work properly: http://www.bootply.com/J3wLVUzbcc Could you tell me please what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @Gonzalo 1) Place the blocks in the order in which they have to stand on a narrow screen. If I understand correctly, the image should be the first. 2) Use a pair of classes. The image gets the `col-md-push-6` class. The text gets the `col-md-pull-6` class.

Comment: that works I was doing it the other way around. Thank you very much!